# My project is Maven based,How can I include .xml files in src\main\resources directory to the final jar package using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to run maven project through spring cloud data flow ,It says files are missing which are present in src\main\resources folder in project. Please help me how can i include .xml files of src\main\resources
directory into jar

Comment: How are you packing your project?

Comment: Those files are included by default, so you must be doing something out of the standard ways.